# How can I make a form to update existing images to a model instance?

Tags: django

I'm making an app that has basic crud functionalities. 
A parent model is extended by a child model through a foreign key relationship. The second model ads images to the first. I've got the basic crud working ie. adding images and relating them to the first model. I have a hard time getting the child model's form to show images that has already been added through making use of an instance. I would like if possible keep the create and update view in a single view function.

I've tried variations of the reverse lookup _set method, but I'm just getting other confusing errors. This is the one that makes most sense to me.

```py
def add_image(request):
    if 'product_id' in request.GET:
        product_id = request.GET['product_id']
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            productimage = form.save(commit=False)
            productimage.product = product
            productimage.save()
            return redirect('dashboard:products')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        if product.productimage_set:
            i = product.productimage_set.all()
            form = ProductImageForm(instance=i)
        else:
            form = ProductImageForm()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/add_image.html', {'form': form})


class ProductImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        exclude = ['product']
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" class="width-100" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
          {{ hidden_field }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
          <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {% render_field field class="form-control"%}
            {% if field.help_text %}
              <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-block" type="submit" value="Add Images"/>
        <a class="btn btn-light btn-block btn-rounded" href="{% url 'dashboard:products' %}">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

I would like the form to show the already added images from the instance I'm calling, should the user want to edit the model instance. Instead, I'm getting an error:

```py
AttributeError at /dashboard/products/add-image/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: please show the template and `forms.py`

Comment: @Moha369 I've added it, thank you

Comment: `forms.py` ????

Comment: Try changing `form = ProductImageForm(instance=i)` to `form = ProductImageForm(instance=product)`